# Avoid tampering the Read-only fields in CRM form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

We have an internal Project management/attendance module implemented in CRM, mostly in JS.

Recently we started facing data issues because our peers started editing/tampering the read-only fields using Browser add-ons like **CRM JS Fiddle** to enable the fields.

We avoided this situation by user training & enabled audit to see the users behavior. Still new joiners exploring this option & forcing us to micro-manage.

Can we do some fail-proof steps to avoid this flaw permanently? Curious to implement the best approach to stop tampering. Ideas welcome.

**Option 1**: To intercept the request using pre-validate plugin & skip these fields from updating

**Option 2**: To move all calculation logic to server, or using calculated fields, etc.

[I don't know if its off-topic, opinion based. still would like to see few response]

Comment: Probably nothing you can do, someone intent enough doesn't even need a form or a browser to send the data to your server, which is why data coming from the clientside **can never be trusted** !

Comment: I wonder what if business started exploring Dev tools like browser toolbar & overwrite the UI data.. I agree nothing we can do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to calculate, validate, or secure data on a CRM form, "[God mode](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2014/07/29/activate-god-mode-in-crm-2013---don-t-let-your-users-see-this)" can definitely present issues.

Some options to avoid it are:

1. Use [Field Level Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309608.aspx#Anchor_4) to make the fields read only.
2. Use the regular security model to make the entire record read-only.
3. Use a pre-operation plugin step or synchronous workflow to perform the calculations and/or validate the data.
4. While it won't prevent the issues, you can write workflows to notify the admin(s) when a user edits a field that should be read only.

You could use JavaScript to set the field to never submit. I have not tested whether God mode overrides this, but since it's a form-based solution we have to assume that a motivated user could figure out how to override it.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_field").setSubmitMode("never");
```

My personal conclusion and practice is to rely on plugins and custom workflows for data-related tasks, rather than JavaScript and business rules. This has a beneficial side-effect that the logic also works if we're importing data rather than entering it on a form.

When possible, I try to use JavaScript and Business Rules for form layout tasks only.

If you do use JavaScript to show the user immediate calculation results on the form, you may have to duplicate the logic in a plugin.

Another idea (which I have not done myself) would be to add an onChange event  to the read-only field(s). That event can recalculate the correct value to frustrate the user's efforts.

For example let's say you have 3 fields: Price, Quantity, and Total.
Price and Quantity are editable, and Total is read-only.

The normal calculation that fires onChange of Price and Quantity is to populate Price * Quantity into Total. Well, you could fire that same calculation when Total changes, which should immediately overwrite any user input with the correct value.